# C# progressbar update from c++ using managed c++ cli

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I am new to C# and C++ mixed programming.

My C# application has a ProgressBar. On click of button, a c++ function is called through c++/CLI wrapper class DLL. It is a time consuming function. Hence I want to show the status update on my c# application's ProgressBar.

The UI  should not be blocked, hence backgroundworker is used; in its DoWork, I invoke the DLL method. Please suggest with code.

[One clue I got is I need to use delegate, but I am new to C++/CLI hence unable to do.]

Code snippets will greatly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a managed method (either C# or C++/CLI) that updates the progress bar, which takes a percentage as a parameter. Have the managed method deal with whatever threading is necessary; you'll likely need to Invoke onto the UI thread.

Convert that into a C++ function pointer, and pass that to your long-running C++ function. Have the long-running C++ function call the function pointer regularly.

You could use a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) here, but I'd skip it, personally. You'd have to do a lot of plumbing to get everything working right, and if all you're interested in is reporting progress, it's easier to do that directly. Instead, I'd take the direct path, and just call your C++ method on a new [`Thread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx?cs-lang=cpp).

Comment: Thank you, David Yaw for your suggestion. Yes I do have a Managed Method which will take a parameter to deal with % complete. It could also have parameters for long running function. However I would appreciate if some small snippet could be shared.

Comment: Try your hand at implementing this, and if you have a specific problem, then please post a question specifically about that. There's plenty of general help available for this type of problem already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to doing it without events

```
C++:

int progressvalue;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl LongRunningMethod(int seconds)
{
    cout << "Started" << endl;

    progressvalue = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        progressvalue = (seconds - ((double)seconds/ (double)i))*10;
        cout << "Progress value in c++: " << progressvalue << endl;
    }
    cout << "Completed" << endl;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl GetProgressUpdate()
{
    return progressvalue;
}
```

here is how to consume it in c#
    c#:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var task = Task.Factory.tartNew(() => {
                               NativeMethods.LongRunningMethod(10);});

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                var val = NativeMethods.GetProgressUpdate();
                ProgressBarMain.Value = val;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you help with Managed C++/cli version of the same with C#, wrapper and C++ combination? I am new, hence it is a request.